# Charging Li-ion pack 6S/10P

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, power-electronics, lithium-ion

I want to make a Li-ion pack, 6S/10P. This is the Li-ion cell type: [sony_us18650vtc6](http://queenbattery.com.cn/index.php?controller=attachment&id_attachment=38)

Also I am using a [BMS from Litech](https://www.litechpower.com/product-detail/HCX-D596V1LI06S70A_01.html).

All cells are the same brand and type, and haven't been used before.

My questions are:

1. Is it is safe to use 10 batteries in parallel?
2. Will they stay balanced after many uses?
3. Does the BMS support CC, CV charging or I should use special charger?
4. Is it dangerous to charge and discharge at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Putting ten cells in parallel isn't necessarily dangerous, as long as you make sure the cells are at the same voltage when you connect them;
2. Parallel cells will balance themselves, the BMS you linked to will balance the cell strings you put in series;
3. **A BMS is not a charger**; you need a proper Li-ion charger;
4. Strictly speaking you can't charge and discharge at the same time; there is net current going in or coming out of the batteries. You can charge and have a load connected at the same time, but it will interfere with the charging algorithm of the charger. There are chargers that will handle this, and some charger modules have a connection for a load, and will power the load from the charger while charging the batteries.

Re 4: How to go about this should maybe be a different question, and product recommendations are off-topic here, but googling around ("Li-ion load sharing charger") should give you general answers on how to set this up, and maybe come up with off-the-shelf solutions.

I have only ever done this for smaller applications, where the charger supplies the load while the battery charges, similar to what is described in this [Application Note](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/01149c.pdf).

There are several charger ICs out there with this functionality built in, like the [MCP73871](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73871-Data-Sheet-20002090E.pdf), but most are for (much) smaller currents than in your application, except maybe the [LTC4000](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4000fb.pdf).

Comment: Very useful and clear answer, thank you dear, do you have any recommendation for lithium ion 6s charger support charging and discharging at the same time?

Comment: See edited answer.